# SQL Server how to escape plus and minus sign?

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping, special-characters

```
Declare @email varchar(max) = '+'
If @email LIKE '%[!#$%&''*+-/=?^_`{|}~]%'
PRINT @email
```

All special characters work fine except the `+` and `-` sign.

I tried to add `\` before the plus sign in the `If` statement, but it doesn't work.

```
Declare @email varchar(max) = '+'
If @email LIKE '%[!#$%&''*\+-/=?^_`{|}~]%'
PRINT @email
```

If I add `\` before the plus sign in both the `Declare` and `If` statement, then it prints `\+`

```
Declare @email varchar(max) = '\+'
If @email LIKE '%[!#$%&''*\+-/=?^_`{|}~]%'
PRINT @email
```

How can I escape the `+` or `-` sign?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the order of the values in the set that you are trying to match.

Because `-` is between two other characters `+-/` is interpreted as a range (`>= '+' and <= '/'`).

This range matches 5 `varchar` characters in my default collation. `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`.

If you are on a collation where `/` sorts before `+` then the range will match nothing. Not even `+` or `/`.

You don't need to escape anything.

Just put the `-` as the first character in the set of values that you are trying to match as in the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals)

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| LIKE '[a-cdf]' | a, b, c, d, or f |
| LIKE '[-acdf]' | -, a, c, d, or f |

Demo

```
WITH CHARS AS
(
SELECT TOP 255 CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)) AS C
FROM sys.all_columns
)
SELECT *
FROM CHARS
WHERE C LIKE '[-!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~]'
```

You can also `ESCAPE` if you prefer though

> Escape characters can be used within the double bracket characters ([
> ]), including to escape a caret (^), hyphen (-), or right bracket (]).